# 5 characters appearing in URL

Tags: azure, url, url-rewriting, dns, redirect

I've been having an issue off and on, hard to reproduce, but happening reasonably regularly.

I have static files on Azure blog storage, and here's the setup - a lot of steps to set up, but it works most of the time - I used [this blog](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn) as my guide:

- index.html lives on the "webfiles" container in blob storage
- the CDN points to /webfiles
- there's a URL rewrite in the CDN setup from / to /index.html
- DNS redirects http://example.com to https://www.example.com
- DNS for www points to the CDN URL

When I go to http://example.com, 9 times out of 10, it properly redirects to https://www.example.com/ and loads the index.html page. However, sometimes, and it seems to generally be on a clean browser with no history, it'll send me to something with 5 extra characters, like https://www.example.com/VeVPe/ where I get a 404 and a BlobNotFound exception - I have no idea what VeVPe is, and it seems to be different for different sites. I have 5 sites set up like this, and it happens to all of them.

If I remove that 5-letter (always seems to be letters, never numbers, but that could just be coincidence) and hit ENTER, it loads properly and I get index.html, or if I just try http://example.com a second time, it works properly. Just seems to be one time.

I've also seen it happen to other sites in the public - there's a local school where the website sometimes redirects me to http://www.example.com/LNnZS/ and a 404 page - that one seems to be the same thing, but it's not HTTPS, so that seems to eliminate at least some of the possible causes. I don't know who their DNS or hosting providers are, so I don't know if it's specific to Azure or GoDaddy.

This happens on Chrome and Edge on desktop and Safari on iPhone, so it's not a browser or computer issue.

If it helps, here's what the URL redirect and rewrite look like on Azure:

[image: azure redirect and rewrite rules]

**EDIT** I'm seeing something interesting when I can catch it in browser tools:

The initial request to http://example.com goes to GoDaddy's IP and returns a 302 Found to Location `/KVZQZ/`. Then there's a request to http://example.com/KVZQZ/ which is returned by GoDaddy's IP with a 301 with a Location `https://www.example.com/KVZQZ/`, and the third request actually makes it to Azure's IP which returns the 404 for BlobNotFound.

So to me, this looks like it's a DNS problem, not a problem with Azure. My DNS settings are:

```
A       @   Forwarded to https://www.example.com
CNAME  www  example.azureedge.net
```

On the forwarding section of the DNS setup, it just forward to https://www.example.com with a 301 forward type. So from what I can tell, nothing too funky here.

Comment: If this is a better fit for webmasters.stackexchange.com, I'd be happy to transfer it over there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of Googling - [This forum post](https://ph.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/My-domain-name-not-resolving-correctly-6-random-characters-are/td-p/60782) shows lots of people who have had the same problem where 5-letter codes get added to their site. It's apparently specific to GoDaddy and no one has been able to convince them to address it. Their workaround is to throw a query string on the forwarding address.

I changed the forwarding address from `https://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com?` and it's working ok now.

I made a request in the browser to `http://example.com` and it redirected me to `https://www.example.com/?/MKSTc/` and loaded up the index.html page - obviously this is not ideal because it's ugly, but I suppose I can write some javascript to do a second redirect back to `https://www.example.com/`